# How to sort out default role from member.roles?

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm trying to make a userinfo command which displays the user's roles. I've separated the roles with a space. But I don't know how to remove the default role out of the roles list.

At the moment, the message looks like this:

```
@@everyone @role @role @role
```

But I don't want that `@@everyone` in there.

My code right now:

```
@client.command(aliases=['whois', 'user'])
async def userinfo(ctx, member: discord.Member):

    embed = discord.Embed(color=member.top_role.color.value, title=f'About {member}')
    embed.add_field(name=f'**Roles [{len(member.roles)}]**', value=' '.join([role.mention for role in member.roles]), inline=True)

    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use: `[role.mention for role in roles[1:]]` instead of: `[role.mention for role in member.roles]` or delete first element. Because you'll get `@everyone` every time.

Documentation for Member.roles:

> A list of Role that the member belongs to. Note that the first element of this list is always the default ‘@everyone’ role.

Before:

[image: Before]

After:

[image]